# Error in eval(expr, envir, enclos) : object not found when using eval

Tags: r, dplyr, data.table, eval

My code is as below:

```
Form_CharSizePorts2 <- function(main, size, var, wght, ret) {

  main.cln <- main %>% 

    select(date, permno, exchcd, eval(parse(text=size)), eval(parse(text=var)), eval(parse(text=wght)),  eval(parse(text=ret))) %>%
    data.table


  Bkpts.NYSE <- main.cln %>% 
    filter(exchcd == 1) %>% 
    group_by(date) %>%
    summarize(var.P70 = quantile(.[[var]], probs=.7, na.rm=TRUE), 
              var.P30 = quantile(.[[var]], probs=.3, na.rm=TRUE),
              size.Med = quantile(.[[size]], probs=.5, na.rm=TRUE))


  main.rank <- main.cln %>%
    merge(Bkpts.NYSE, by="date", all.x=TRUE) %>%
    mutate(Size = ifelse(.[[size]]<size.Med, "Small", "Big"),
           Var = ifelse(.[[var]]<var.P30, "Low", ifelse(.[[var]]>var.P70, "High", "Neutral")),
           Port = paste(Size, Var, sep="."))

  Ret <- main.rank %>% 
    group_by(date, Port) %>%
    summarize(ret.port = weighted.mean(.[[ret]], .[[wght]], na.rm=TRUE)) %>% 
    spread(Port, ret.port) %>% 
    mutate(Small = (Small.High + Small.Neutral + Small.Low)/3,
           Big = (Big.High + Big.Neutral + Big.Low)/3,
           SMB = Small - Big,
           High = (Small.High + Big.High)/2,
           Low = (Small.Low + Big.Low)/2,
           HML = High - Low)

  return(Ret)
}











Form_FF4Ports <- function(dt) {
  dt.cln <- dt %>% 
    group_by(permno) %>%
    mutate(lag.ret.12t2 = lag(ret.12t2, 1))

  output <- dt.cln %>%
    group_by(date) %>%
    summarize(MyMkt = weighted.mean(retadj.1mn, w=port.weight, na.rm=TRUE)) %>%
    as.data.frame %>%
    merge(Form_CharSizePorts2(dt.cln, "lag.ME.Jun", "lag.BM.FF", "port.weight", "retadj.1mn"),
          by="date", all.x=TRUE) %>% 
    transmute(date, MyMkt, MySMB=SMB, MySMBS=Small, MySMBB=Big, MyHML=HML, MyHMLH=High, MyHMLL=Low) %>%
    merge(Form_CharSizePorts2(dt.cln, "lag.ME.Jun", "lag.ret.12t2", "port.weight", "retadj.1mn"), 
          by="date", all.x=TRUE) %>% 
    transmute(date, MyMkt, MySMB, MySMBS, MySMBB, MyHML, MyHMLH, MyHMLL, MyUMD=HML, MyUMDU=High, MyUMDD=Low)
  return(output)
}




dt.myFF4.m <- Form_FF4Ports(data.both.FF.m)
```

Part of my data is as below:

```
        date permno shrcd exchcd    cfacpr   cfacshr shrout     prc vol retx retadj.1mn       me port.weight datadate
1  Dec 1925  10006    10      1  7.412625  7.260000    600  109.00  NA   NA         NA 65.40000          NA     <NA>
2  Dec 1925  10022    10      1  9.365437  9.365437    200   56.00  NA   NA         NA 11.20000          NA     <NA>
3  Dec 1925  10030    10      1  9.969793  9.155520    156  150.00  NA   NA         NA 23.40000          NA     <NA>
4  Dec 1925  10057    11      1  4.000000  4.000000    500   12.25  NA   NA         NA  6.12500          NA     <NA>
5  Dec 1925  10073    10      1  0.200000  0.200000    138   17.50  NA   NA         NA  2.41500          NA     <NA>
6  Dec 1925  10081    10      1  1.000000  1.000000   1192    9.00  NA   NA         NA 10.72800          NA     <NA>
7  Dec 1925  10102    10      1 18.137865 18.000000    201  109.75  NA   NA         NA 22.05975          NA     <NA>
8  Dec 1925  10110    10      1  1.010000  1.000000    500   10.50  NA   NA         NA  5.25000          NA     <NA>
9  Dec 1925  10129    10      1  1.000000  1.000000    270 -132.00  NA   NA         NA 35.64000          NA     <NA>
10 Dec 1925  10137    11      1 21.842743 20.920870    613   71.75  NA   NA         NA 43.98275          NA     <NA>
   comp.count at revt ib dvc BE OpProf GrProf Cflow Inv AstChg Davis.bkeq d.shares ret.12t2 ME.Dec ME.Jun BM.FF OpIB
1          NA NA   NA NA  NA NA     NA     NA    NA  NA     NA         NA       NA       NA     NA     NA    NA   NA
2          NA NA   NA NA  NA NA     NA     NA    NA  NA     NA         NA       NA       NA     NA     NA    NA   NA
3          NA NA   NA NA  NA NA     NA     NA    NA  NA     NA         NA       NA       NA     NA     NA    NA   NA
4          NA NA   NA NA  NA NA     NA     NA    NA  NA     NA         NA       NA       NA     NA     NA    NA   NA
5          NA NA   NA NA  NA NA     NA     NA    NA  NA     NA         NA       NA       NA     NA     NA    NA   NA
6          NA NA   NA NA  NA NA     NA     NA    NA  NA     NA         NA       NA       NA     NA     NA    NA   NA
7          NA NA   NA NA  NA NA     NA     NA    NA  NA     NA         NA       NA       NA     NA     NA    NA   NA
8          NA NA   NA NA  NA NA     NA     NA    NA  NA     NA         NA       NA       NA     NA     NA    NA   NA
9          NA NA   NA NA  NA NA     NA     NA    NA  NA     NA         NA       NA       NA     NA     NA    NA   NA
10         NA NA   NA NA  NA NA     NA     NA    NA  NA     NA         NA       NA       NA     NA     NA    NA   NA
   GrIA CFP.FF BM.m CFP.m lag.ME.Jun lag.BM.FF lag.OpIB lag.AstChg
1    NA     NA   NA    NA         NA        NA       NA         NA
2    NA     NA   NA    NA         NA        NA       NA         NA
3    NA     NA   NA    NA         NA        NA       NA         NA
4    NA     NA   NA    NA         NA        NA       NA         NA
5    NA     NA   NA    NA         NA        NA       NA         NA
6    NA     NA   NA    NA         NA        NA       NA         NA
7    NA     NA   NA    NA         NA        NA       NA         NA
8    NA     NA   NA    NA         NA        NA       NA         NA
9    NA     NA   NA    NA         NA        NA       NA         NA
10   NA     NA   NA    NA         NA        NA       NA         NA
```

When I run the rode, I got the error message `Error in eval(expr, envir, enclos) : object 'lag.ME.Jun' not found`.

I guess the reason could be that I used the `eval(parse(text = ))` function here, and the environment is not set up correctly. However, other than this function, I am not sure which approach I should use when creating a universal purpose function suitable for data with different column names.

Specifically, I would like to know how I can use my function for different data frames without having to change the column names before I use them in my function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your issue is discussed, and solved, in the 'Programming with dplyr' [vignette](http://dplyr.tidyverse.org/articles/programming.html).

The bottomline is instead of quoting `lag.ME.Jun` yourself by referring to it using `"lag.ME.Jun"`, you should rely on `enquo(lag.ME.Jun)` and `!!lag.ME.Jun`. However, this would mean that it should be in the function call.

Your function at several other points also refers to variables that are not created in the function environment (e.g. `exchcd`, `date`), so R will currently throw errors on any dataset that does not contain these variables. In general, it is unwise for functions to rely on inputs that were not part of the function call.

Comment: I figured out the issue. Thanks so much